# Duplicates in table MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

Ok i have table in MySQL

SMESTAJ and column MESTO

I want to get all values from row MESTO, but no duplicates

Can somebody help me and tell me the correct MySQL Query?

Comment: Do you mean column MESTO?  If so, `SELECT DISTINCT mesto FROM smestaj`

Comment: I dont want same value

Comment: use this query "SELECT * FROM `SMESTAJ` WHERE `FIELD_NAME`='MESTO' LIMIT 1"

Answer (score 3):

Assuming: Table name  = 'SMESTAJ'
          Column name = 'MESTO'

```
SELECT DISTINCT MESTO FROM SMESTAJ
```

You can read more about the DISTINCT keyword [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Answer (score 2):

is what you are looking for:

```
select distinct columnName from table;
```

if that is the case:

```
select distinct SMESTAJ from MESTO
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW mesto FROM SMESTAJ
```

Generally, the correct format is: SELECT DISTINCTROW row FROM table.

Hope this helps.